# WordPress: How to implement categorised CTAs

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm very new to wordpress and therefore slightly lost on where to begin.

I would like to implement a blog post CTA section where the administrator can create new CTAs and attach them to blog posts of a particular category. For example the admin may create a CTA about pet food and assign it to the category 'pet food', this post will display only those CTAs which are in the category 'pet food'.

From research I have come across Wordpress custom post types, but due to lack of experience, Im unsure if this is the correct way of implementing this functionality.

Comment: Are you looking to generate specific URL's or just custom blog categories, becasue may be better off with using the standard structre of wordpres and then editing your permalink structure.

if you want something completely custom then post types may be the way to go, but you will need to check out the docs on [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_post_type/). This is something i have done before. You need to be clear about your requirements before you attempt to do this.

Comment: @CallistusAsirvatham I would like the user to be able to specify a custom URL for a CTA when they create one

Comment: We need more detail on how this would be structured,  for example domain/category/custom-part/blog-name

Comment: [This](https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-create-custom-permalinks-in-wordpress/) may help

Answer (score 1):

**Just Follow the following steps**

**Step 1:** past the code in the function.php file

```
function create_posttype() {

register_post_type( 'Events',
// CPT Options

array(
  'labels' => array(
   'name' => __( 'CTA' ),
   'singular_name' => __( 'CTA' )
  ),
  'public' => true,
  'has_archive' => false,
  'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'CTA'),
  'taxonomies' => array( 'category' ),
   'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor','thumbnail' ),

 )
);
}
// Hooking up our function to theme setup
add_action( 'init', 'create_posttype' );
```

this will create a post type of "**CTA**".

**Step 2:** Fetch the Blog of a specific category in a post type.

```
function blogcts() {
$args=array(
  'posts_per_page' => 100,    
  'post_type' => 'CTA', // posttype name
  'order' => 'ASC',
  'cat'=> 5  //category id
);
$wp_query = new WP_Query( $args );

$pp .='';

while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post();
$feat_image = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($productPost->ID));       //feature 
$contents = get_the_content();                                                     //Fetch 
$contents_new = substr($contents, 0, 50);
$excerpt = get_the_excerpt();

$pp .=' <div class="">
<div class="">
<img src="'.$feat_image .'" class="" alt="">
</div>
<p>'. get_the_title() .'</p>
<hr>
<p>'.$contents_new.'</p>
<p class=""><a href="'.  get_the_permalink() .'"> More</a></p>


    </div>';
endwhile;
    $pp .='</div>';
return '' .$pp.'';
}
add_shortcode('srtcode_blogcts', 'blogcts');
```

**Step 3:** Paste the shortcode into the page.

```
[srtcode_blogcts]
```

or template file

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[srtcode_blogcts]'); ?>
```

Comment: `  'cat'=> 5  //category id` Im confused by this line in step two. Wouldn't this number be dependant on what category the post is in? 

Im wanting to only show CTAs that have the same category as the blogpost

Comment: Send me the screen short